# Deserializing JSON Object containing another object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize this JSON string using Newtonsoft.Json library. But the returned deserialized object allways returns null. I think it's related to the address object inside the player object.

This is the JSON string

```
{  
   "player":{  
      "id":"ed704e61-f92b-4505-b087-8a47ca4d1eaf",
      "firstName":"Jack",
      "lastName":"Russel",
      "nickname":"Barky",
      "dateOfBirth":"1995-08-16T00:00:00",
      "sex":"m",
      "address":{  
         "street":"Elmstreet",
         "number":"5",
         "alphaNumber":"",
         "poBox":"",
         "postalCode":"90001",
         "city":"Los Angeles",
         "country":"United States"
      },
      "email":[  
         "barky@dog.com",
         "barky@mydogpension.com"
      ],
      "phone":[  
         "0123 45 67 89 10"
      ]
   },
   "requestReference":2000,
   "requestStatus":"Request OK",
   "requestDetails":null
}
```

These are the RootObject, Player and Address classes. It's the RootObject's Player object which keeps returning a null value for the JSON string above. So upon calling offcourse a nullreference exception is being thrown:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Player player { get; set; }
    public int requestReference { get; set; }
    public string requestStatus { get; set; }
    public string requestDetails { get; set; }
}    

public class Address
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string alphaNumber { get; set; }
    public string poBox { get; set; }
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string nickname { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string sex { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public List<string> email { get; set; }
    public List<string> phone { get; set; }
}
```

This is the line of code used to Deserialize:

`RootObject playerRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(_the_json_string_shown_above);`

Comment: Your code works for me with Json.Net 7

Comment: All deserializes fine for me - just tested your code verbatim. Using Newtonsoft.Json version 9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I was using Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.2.19309.
I had to add a JsonProperty attribute to the Address object inside the Player class. Then the object gets deserialized just fine.

```
public class Player
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string nickname { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string sex { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public List<string> email { get; set; }
    public List<string> phone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So what version of Newtonsoft.Json were you using?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.2.19309 is the one in use for this project.

Comment: Very strange it wouldn't deserialize without the `[JsonProperty]` attribute, when it worked fine with mine and @heinzbeinz's ones. Glad you got it working in the end, though :) Happy coding!